# How do I redirect output to a variable in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script like that

```
genhash --use-ssl -s $IP -p 443 --url $URL | grep MD5 | grep -c $MD5
```

I want to get stream generated by genhash in a variable. How do I redirect it into a variable `$hash` to compare inside a conditional?

```
if [ $hash -ne 0 ]
  then echo KO
  exit 0
else echo -n OK
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: This question is the older than the linked answer. Therefore the linked answer is the duplicate, and should be marked as "asked before", not this one.

Comment: Bash and Shell are different things, hence it's no duplicate. Shell doesn't support all of bash's features.

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Use the `$( ... )` construct:

```
hash=$(genhash --use-ssl -s $IP -p 443 --url $URL | grep MD5 | grep -c $MD5)
```

Comment: This captures the output of a command, but it does not use a redirect. If you actually need to use a redirect because of a more complex need, See my answer. Google brought you here, right? Why go somewhere else to find the answer you searched for?

Comment: actually not an answer on OP question

Comment: @BrunoBronosky this is what worked for me: `result=$(( $your_command ) 2>&1)`

Comment: @Kayvar when you use `$( ... )` it uses new subshell, so the result of command can be not the same as in the primary shell

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you made it clear whether this only captures STDOUT or if it also captures STDERR. It would also be very helpful if you could show how to print the exit code of the command inside `$(...)`

Answer (score 285):

**TL;DR**

To store `"abc"` into `$foo`:

```
echo "abc" | read foo
```

But, because pipes create forks, you have to use `$foo` before the pipe ends, so...

```
echo "abc" | ( read foo; date +"I received $foo on %D"; )
```

---

Sure, all these other answers show ways to not do what the OP asked, but that really screws up the rest of us who searched for the OP's question.

#### The answer to the question is to use the **[`read`](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html)** command.

#### Here's how you do it

```
# I would usually do this on one line, but for readability...
series | of | commands \
| \
(
  read string;
  mystic_command --opt "$string" /path/to/file
) \
| \
handle_mystified_file
```

#### Here is what it is doing and why it is important:

1. Let's pretend that the `series | of | commands` is a very complicated series of piped commands.
2. `mystic_command` can accept the content of a file as stdin in lieu of a file path, but **not the `--opt` arg** therefore it must come in as a variable. The command outputs the modified content and would commonly be redirected into a file or piped to another command. (E.g. `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, etc.)
3. `read` takes stdin and places it into the variable `$string`
4. Putting the `read` and the `mystic_command` into a "sub shell" via parenthesis is not necessary but makes it flow like a continuous pipe as if the 2 commands where in a separate script file.

There is always an alternative, and in this case the alternative is ugly and unreadable compared to my example above.

```
# my example above as a oneliner
series | of | commands | (read string; mystic_command --opt "$string" /path/to/file) | handle_mystified_file

# ugly and unreadable alternative
mystic_command --opt "$(series | of | commands)" /path/to/file | handle_mystified_file
```

My way is entirely *chronological* and logical. The alternative starts with the 4th command and shoves commands 1, 2, and 3 into command substitution.

I have a real world example of this in [this script](https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/45649cbb5ad3bc689e9523a3a59a1d7d) but I didn't use it as the example above because it has some other crazy/confusing/distracting bash magic going on also.

Comment: I too believe this is to be the right answer. There are situations where $(...) does not work while piping is accepted everywhere.

Comment: Don't forget that semicolon at the end! :)

Comment: @Pat, semicolon to go where? I don't have a handy mystic command but it looks right?

Comment: At first I thought @Pat was suggesting that I put a `;` after the mystic_command` or maybe that I remove the one after the `read`. Because of the smiley, I figured that @Pat was just teasing me about the inconsistency. The reason it is inconsistent is that it is the minimum needed if you condense it to a one-liner. I did test this with a utility I call arg_barf. It is basically a stand in for any command that I use when prototyping a bash script. It will accept stdin and any arguments, write them to a temp file, and optionally cat a file to stdout/stderr and return a non-zero status.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the semicolon at the end of `read string;`

Comment: @RichardBronosky Thanks for posting this answer. Can one access the variable in the parent process (e.g., farther along in the pipe line, say at the `handle_mystified_file` portion)? This seems to be impossible since `read` is operating in a child process, which cannot affect variables in the parent process. I am trying to split the output from a process using `tee` and "reconnect" the `tee`-divided processes later, by reading the output of one as an argument in the other.

Comment: Same question as above i.e. accessing variable in parent process. Also, is there any way for the variable to store a multi line string?

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `echo "test" | read ROLE_X; 
echo $ROLE_X` doesn't print anything.

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn, That doesn't work because pipes create process forks. That another reason that I had to add parenthesis. `echo "test" | (read ROLE_X; echo $ROLE_X )` Read more about this forking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13764018/117471

Comment: Still doesn't work with parenthesis. `ls | (read $x; echo $x)` prints just the first line of the ls output. 'read' can't read more than one line of output.

Comment: @PhilGoetz That's because you have `read $x;`. The `$` makes it a variable access (so you saying "read into this variable access"). It should be `ls | (read x; echo $x)`.

Comment: If your stdin is going to have multiple lines, you can use `read -d '' string`.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, I'm not sure why you can say words like "all these other answers show ways to not do what the OP asked". As I understand `$(...)` were the one that were accepted. Please consider describing your case so it will be clear in which case `read` is the only viable option. Note that you still can have redirects inside of `echo $(cat <<< "works")` and you can use `echo "$(pstree)"` to get multi-line strings.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky "If your stdin is going to have multiple lines, you can use read -d '' string." 
Please consider putting this into your answer, at first I'd found your solution completely unusable in my case. The thing about the parentheses being required is important too (variable to which read assigns is empty in a following command without parentheses).

Comment: I added a quick TL;DR for the impatient Googler. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ony I say those words because the title of the question is "How do I redirect output to a variable in shell?" and my answer was the first to actually "**redirect** output to a variable". I LOVE "command substitution" and use it all the time (as does any half decent hack). But, when I need to redirect output instead, I usually have to Google for it **even though I wrote this answer** because I don't do it very often. This is the top hit on Google, so I wanted it to have the answer to the question asked.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, it is good to have alternatives. I just trying to say that it would be more useful if you'll describe why you had to use this approach over the accepted one. And I should confess that your words were a bit bold from my point of view. People often say one thing but in the end they probably wanted to say something else and it is part of communication to look through words. This is especially true when people are speaking about something they don't know yet.  Apparently substitution was fine since it was accepted. Would be nice to know your case were this answer is more suitable.

Comment: `echo "abc" | (read foo; echo $foo)` works fine in the terminal but for some reason fails when used in a bash script.

Comment: @BiBi I'm not sure why you are having that issue. I tried pasting your line into a file tested it many ways. https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/65a8307152363416803bc1969d6a67d9

Comment: How do I _append_ to `$foo` though?

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius That is going to be very tricky because of the way pipes create forks. you can read more about this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764018/117471 I could append in many ways, but without knowing your specifics it would most certainly be suboptimal. I'm fairly certain there is no way to accomplish my "chronological and logical" objective when trying to append. For example call this a few times: `read foo < <( echo -n $foo; date +%s, ); echo "value of foo: '$foo'"`

Comment: I used this to create a bash function I can reuse more simply.

`tovar(){read $1; echo $"$1";}` then
`echo 'content' > file.txt; cat file.txt | tovar somevariable` then
`echo $somevariable => content`

Comment: @MarioOlivioFlores, that doesn't work. I can't even tell what it's supposed to do.

Comment: the spacing makes it really hard to read. Basically, I just created a function so I could pipe to a variable.  If my desired variable name were `myvar`, I could do `echo 'value' | tovar myvar` Useful for my usecase.

Comment: What advantage does this `read` construct provide over just using `xargs`?

Answer (score 82):

```
read hash < <(genhash --use-ssl -s $IP -p 443 --url $URL | grep MD5 | grep -c $MD5)
```

This technique uses Bash's "[process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)" not to be confused with "[command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)".

Here are a few good references:

- http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection
- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html
- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html ☚ for comparison

Comment: This needs more upvote. The only solution that worked for me these days.

Comment: This is useful when the subcommands must not be run in a subshell. Thanks!

Comment: I wish more people understood the use of `<(…)` it's pure awesomeness. OP should have given an explanation. Basically, it runs a subprocess, but instead of piping it, it returns a file descriptor. This allows you to use commands in places where you need files. For example (as root) `vimdiff /etc/sysconfig/iptables <(iptables-save)` which ends up opening a filename similar to `/proc/23565/fd/63`. Yes, `vim` can accept `-` as a filename and read from `stdin` but that's just an example. May things don't use `-` or are much more legible with the command order that `<()` allows.

Comment: @IntrepidDude I edited the answer to include what you (and others) need to know. Thanks for asking. This will benefit everyone.

Comment: It looks like this only captures STDOUT and not also STDERR

Comment: got `syntax error near unexpected token `<'`, running on macos Catalina

Comment: This one works perfectly and it's easy to read.

Answer (score 21):

I guess compatible way:

```
hash=`genhash --use-ssl -s $IP -p 443 --url $URL | grep MD5 | grep -c $MD5`
```

but I prefer

```
hash="$(genhash --use-ssl -s $IP -p 443 --url $URL | grep MD5 | grep -c $MD5)"
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning compatibility. That was the method that worked on my environment, when the others didn't.

Comment: There's no need for quotes around `$(...)`.

Comment: Yes, there IS a need. 
Eg. if there is a * in the output, depending on how you handle it later, it'll try to expand it as a glob.

Comment: @Koshinae, it will try to expand for `echo $hash`. But it will keep `*` as-is if you'll do `hash=$(echo '*'0); echo "$hash"`

Comment: If the result is multiple words, it will create an array no? So by surrounding it with quotes it creates a string instead of an array of strings. Not really sure, relatively new to bash

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin, when I need to store words in array I use `ab=($(echo a b))` . Otherwise it will assign as a string.

Answer (score 9):

If a pipeline is too complicated to wrap in `$(...)`, consider writing a function. Any local variables available at the time of definition will be accessible.

```
function getHash {
  genhash --use-ssl -s $IP -p 443 --url $URL | grep MD5 | grep -c $MD5
}
hash=$(getHash)
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions

Comment: You might even want to write a complicated pipeline into a shell script of its own and call it `hash=$(getHash.sh)` -- shell scripts would be available in a new terminal, and even after a reboot.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
hash=$(genhash --use-ssl -s $IP -p 443 --url $URL)
```

or

```
hash=`genhash --use-ssl -s $IP -p 443 --url $URL`
```

If you want to result of the entire pipe to be assigned to the variable, you can use the entire pipeline in the above assignments.

Answer (score 3):

I got error sometimes when using `` $(`code`) `` constructor.

Finally i got some approach to that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7902174/2480481

Basically, using Tee to read again the ouput and putting it into a variable.
Theres how you see the normal output then read it from the ouput.

is not? I guess your current task genhash will output just that, a single string hash so might work for you.

Im so neewbie and still looking for full output & save into 1 command.
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function calling it as the command you want to invoke. In this case, I need to use the **ruok** command.

Then, call the function and assign its result into a variable. In this case, I am assigning the result to the variable **health**.

```
function ruok {
  echo ruok | nc *ip* 2181
}

health=echo ruok *ip*
```