# redirect command output into variable and standard output in ksh

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

I have some shell command. I would like to write the output to the standard output and save it into variable as well.
I'd like to solve it with one command.
I have tried these things.

```
ls > $VAR          # redirects the output to file which name is stored in $VAR
ls | tee -a $VAR   # writes to standard output as well as in file which name is stored in $VAR
VAR=`ls`           # output into $VAR, but it is not sent to standard output
VAR=`ls`;echo $VAR # ok, it works but these are two commands
```

Any idea?

Comment: Just curious about the 1 line limitation. that makes me thing youre not the root of, of also a user of the system target. I can't figure out why do you have that limitation. Anyway i have posted you a "doyourself" answer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

How about:

```
VAR=$(ls | tee /dev/tty)
```

Comment: Depending on your OS, `var=$(ls | tee /proc/$$/fd/1)` might work too.

Comment: Even if this is working perfectly, i post you an  "do-it-yourself way" example.
Im a Linux/bash noob, but i like learn those tips :D

Comment: Note that this (tee) only catches STDOUT output and that programs often do not color it (i.e. use `VAR=$(ls --color | tee /dev/tty)` to get coloured output).

Answer (score 3):

great answer from @Gary_Barker, but this isn't possible on all systems.

On our teamcity there isn't a char-console.
And there is another little problem.

If I use

`VAR=$(ls -1); echo $VAR`

it isn't the same like `ls -1`

My solution works, if it doesn't matter, that the output comes from error pipe.

`VAR=$(ls -1 | tee >&2)`

Comment: Make sure to double quote the echo if the result is more than one line. `VAR=$(ls -1); echo "$VAR"`. otherwise it gets squished into a single line

Comment: @hoss can you explain why this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, `` VAR=`ls`;echo $VAR `` is OK but you don't like because has 2 commands on it.

While @Gary-Barker is working, i have not check on all systems. If you got problem with tee or another, you can build your own ALWAYS.

I don't know if you know that, but a lot of the programs you can use on Linux are just a bunch of code using the small binarys on system.
While this is true, there's no sense about use 1 or 2 commans, because the final execution is really a bunch of little ones.

So, if your real problem is that you can only write a single command in your target, you can write your own "app", by making a sh script in /sbin folder an leaving it without .sh extension (because these are excecuted with ./ or sh prefix and not by name)

I wrote that as example:

`#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 ]
then
    VAR=$*; echo $VAR
fi`

For this example i have make the file /sbin/varrun. I've tried it with the folling commands with successful (normal) output:

- `varrun ls`
- `varrun uname`
- `varrun uname -a`

Note that i've not used "quotes" on commands with spaces.