# How to store an output of shell script to a variable in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix

i have a shell script "script.sh" which gives output as "success" or "Failed" when i execute in unix window.
Now i want to store the output of script.sh into a unix command variable. `say $a = {output of script.sh}`

Comment: Pretty much the same as [redirect command output into variable and standard output in ksh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901568/redirect-command-output-into-variable-and-standard-output-in-ksh)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Two simple examples to capture output the `pwd` command:

```
$ b=$(pwd)
$ echo $b
/home/user1
```

or

```
$ a=`pwd`
$ echo $a
/home/user1
```

The first way is preferred. Note that there can't be any spaces after the `=` for this to work.

Example using a short script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hi there"
```

then:

```
$ ./so.sh
hi there
$ a=$(so.sh)
$ echo $a
hi there
```

In general a more flexible approach would be to return an exit value from the command and use it for further processing, though sometimes we just may want to capture the simple output from a command.

Comment: yes it returns a string. I just want to store the value to $a

Comment: can a command be replaced by script.sh ? like : $a=`script.sh` will that store the out put of a script.sh ?

Answer (score 7):

Suppose you want to store the result of an echo command

```
echo hello   
x=$(echo hello)  
echo "$x",world!
```

output:

```
hello  
hello,world!
```

Comment: @NitsanBaleli This is a answer, not a question

Answer (score 4):

You should probably re-write the script to return a value rather than output it.  Instead of:

```
a=$( script.sh ) # Now a is a string, either "success" or "Failed"
case "$a" in
   success) echo script succeeded;;
   Failed) echo script failed;;
esac
```

you would be able to do:

```
if script.sh > /dev/null; then
    echo script succeeded
else
    echo script failed
fi
```

It is much simpler for other programs to work with you script if they do not have to parse the output.  This is a simple change to make.  Just `exit 0` instead of printing `success`, and `exit 1` instead of printing `Failed`.  Of course, you can also print those values as well as exiting with a reasonable return value, so that wrapper scripts have flexibility in how they work with the script.

Comment: As a side note, you'll want to use `success` and `failed` (note the consistent capitalization) in any real code, or things will get confusing quickly.

Answer (score 3):

```
export a=$(script.sh)
```

Hope this helps. Note there are no spaces between variable and =. To echo the output

```
echo $a
```

Comment: when the script will execute ? after submitting echo $a? or after export ?

Comment: Why are you exporting `a`?  You should use double quotes around `$a` in the `echo` statement.

Comment: @login it will run the script in a subshell and wait for it until it quits, that subshell's streams will be pointing to the variable "a", meaning that everything they output will be written to the variable instead of the standard output of your main shell

Comment: @SvenMarnach I didn't know how the OP wanted to use the variable, exporting makes it available to child processes

Comment: @logan $(command) is a way to run commands and capture output

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the script with a preceding dot, this will put the exported variables in the current environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
export output="SUCCESS"
```

Then execute it like so

```
chmod +x /tmp/test.sh
. /tmp/test.sh
```

When you need the entire output and not just a single value, just put the output in a variable like the other answers indicate

Comment: No reason for "export" when using source. Also, for only a single value, exit status or stdout seem that they would make more sense.