# ksh storing result of a command to a variable

Tags: linux, command, ksh

I want to store the result of a command to a variable in my shell script. I cant seem to get it to work. I want the most recently dated file in the directory.

```
PRODUCT= 'ls -t /some/dir/file* | head -1 | xargs -n1 basename'
```

it wont work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store an output of shell script to a variable in Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948303/how-to-store-an-output-of-shell-script-to-a-variable-in-unix)

Answer (score 5):

you have two options, either `$` or backsticks`` ` ``.

1) `x=$(ls -t /some/dir/file* | head -1 | xargs -n1 basename)`

or

2) `` x=`ls -t /some/dir/file* | head -1 | xargs -n1 basename` ``

```
echo $x
```

**Edit:** removing unnecessary bracket for (2).

Comment: You must not have spaces around the equal sign: your code is attempting to run the command `x` with 2 arguments.

Comment: Thank you glenn and doniyor. It was a combination of the space and the $().

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you're having is that the command needs to be surrounded by back-ticks rather than single quotes. This is known as 'Command Substitution'.

Bash allows you to use `$()` for command substitution, but this is not available in all shells. I don't know if it's available in KSH; if it is, it's probably not available in all versions.

If the `$()` syntax is available in your version of ksh, you should definitely use it; it's easier to read (back ticks are too easy to confuse with single quotes); back-ticks are also hard to nest.

This only addresses one of the problems with your command, however: `ls` returns directories as well as files, so if the most recent thing modified in the specified directory is a sub-directory, that is what you will see.

If you only want to see files, I suggest using some version of the following (I'm using Bash, which supports default variables, you'll probably have to play around with the syntax of `$1`)

```
lastfile () 
{ 
    find ${1:-.} -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | sed 's/[^[:space:]]\+ //'
}
```

This runs find on the directory, and only pulls files from that directory. It formats all of the files like this:

```
2012-08-29+16:21:40.0000000000 ./.sqlite_history
2013-01-14+08:52:14.0000000000 ./.davmail.properties
2012-04-04+16:16:40.0000000000 ./.DS_Store
2010-04-21+15:49:00.0000000000 ./.joe_state
2008-09-05+17:15:28.0000000000 ./.hplip.conf
2012-01-31+13:12:28.0000000000 ./.oneclick
```

sorts the list, takes the last line, and chops off everything before the first space.

Comment: `ksh` supports `$()`.  I think POSIX requires it, these days.  It's certainly the preferred form, especially if you need to nest them.

Comment: Instead of sed, you could use `cut -d" " -f 2-`

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still new to ksh. The company I work for, uses ksh to do some automation on their servers. I will try this tomorrow and let you know if I have any success.

Answer (score 1):

You want `$()` ([preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed)) or backticks (``) (older style), rather than single quotes:

```
PRODUCT=$(ls -t /some/dir/file* | head -1 | xargs -n1 basename)
```

or

```
PRODUCT=`ls -t /some/dir/file* | head -1 | xargs -n1 basename`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need both quotes to ensure you keep the name even if it contains spaces, and also in case you later want more than 1 file, and "$(..)" to run commands in background

I believe you also need the '-1' option to ls, otherwise you could have several names per lines (you only keep 1 line, but it could be several files)

```
PRODUCT="$(ls -1t /some/dir/file* | head -1 | xargs -n1 basename)"
```

Please do not put space around the "=" variable assignments (as I saw on other solutions here) , as it's not very compatible as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

Your version corrected:

```
PRODUCT=$(ls -t /some/dir/file* | head -1 | xargs -n1 basename)
```

Or simpler:

```
PRODUCT=$(cd /some/dir && ls -1t file* | head -1)
```

- change to the directory
- list one filename per line and sort by time/date
- grab the first line