# bash script catch other subscript output

Tags: bash, shell, psql

I have a simple script creating database

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
psql -d track -q -f "$DIR"/create.sql > RESULT
RESULT="$(psql -d track -q -f "$DIR"/create.sql)"
echo $RESULT
```

this:

```
$ bash MakeDB.sh  > result
```

produces empty result file

psql produces some log info that is output to terminal, the thing is I can't redirect that info, I want to pass it further as a result.

Is there a way to store psql output? It would be best if it wasn't printed in the terminal.

Comment: This isn't relevant, but you should change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` in the first line if you want the script to be executed using bash. Then you can `chmod +x` it and run it just as `./MakeDB.sh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `psql produces some log info that is output to terminal, the thing is I can't redirect that info, I want to pass it further as a result.`

Have your script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
psql -d track -q -f "$DIR"/create.sql > RESULT 2>&1
psql -d track -q -f "$DIR"/create.sql
```

You can then redirect `stderr` to same file as the `stdout` using this syntax:

```
bash MakeDB.sh > result 2>&1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as-is as it will go into the variable, which I don't think is what is wanted. So this answer may need to be combined with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451278/bash-capture-stdout-to-a-variable-but-still-display-it-in-the-console

Comment: @RobinGreen: Oh yes good point, I missed that. But since since all OP is doing with `$RESULT` to echo it. OP can avoid storing the output in `$RESULT` and let all output/error be written to terminal. Edited it further.

Comment: I can't invoke create.sql 2 times putting the result in a variable and then printing it would do, but RESULT is always empty

Comment: You don't need to call it twice. I just copied the script from question and that had this call twice.