# How to fix initscr bug with backquotes?

Tags: c, linux, unix, ncurses

I have a real big problem with the function `initscr()`.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
 WINDOW *win;

 initscr();
 printw("lol");
 getch();
 refresh();
 endwin();
 return (0);
}
```

When I compile this code and I execute `./a.out` it's okay, but when I did

```
lol=`./a.out`
```

the `initscr` didn't appear. I read in the man about the function `newterm` but it was the same.

Comment: Why would you like `./a.out` to work correctly with your terminal if you catch its output into a shell variable?

Comment: First thanks to the answer. I want to use them both...

Comment: The output of a program that uses ncurses is intended to be written to a terminal (or emulator). It's not meant to be captured in a variable or written to a file. You *can* do that if you like, but then it's not going to the screen so it won't look right.

Comment: Okay but how its possible ? thanks

Comment: How is *what* possible? Your question doesn't describe what you're trying to do. What do want to see when you execute the command, and what do you want/expect the variable `$lol` to contain after you execute it? Your only problem description is that "the `initscr` didn't appear", but frankly that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. I use `newterm` with `stderr` as output filedescriptor and it works.

```
int         main(int ac, char **av)
{
  SCREEN    *win;

  win = newterm(NULL, stderr, stdin);
  printw("lol");
  getch();
  refresh();
  endwin();
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: So when you run ``lol=`./a.out` ``, you should get nothing in `$lol`. What's the point of that?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the output of any command on the terminal using the [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) utility, which is often installed by default.  It saves all of the output of your program to a file named `typescript`, and does not interfere with the program.  With Linux, you might run it as follows:

```
script -c ./a.out
```

(With other systems, such as OSX, you may not have the `-c` option: there is no POSIX standard for `script`).

However, you may find the results unexpected, since they would be mixed with escape sequences.  For instance, running your program with `TERM` set to `vt100`, and showing non-printing characters in printable form using [`unmap`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:unmap), I see this:

```
Script started on Thu 03 Dec 2015 08:09:15 PM EST
\n
\E(B
\E)0
\E[1;40r
\E[m^O
\E[?7h
\E[H
\E[Jlol\r
\E[40;1H\r
\E[?1l
\E>
\nScript done on Thu 03 Dec 2015 08:09:16 PM EST
\n
```

Rather than try to separate the message from the escape sequences, some programs (such as [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html)) intentionally write their messages on the standard error while using the standard output for screen updates.  Or (using `newterm`) you can reverse that, making it simple to obtain a message.

Here is a revised program using that approach:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void
show(const char *msg)
{
    printw("%s", msg);
    if (!isatty(fileno(stdout)))
    puts(msg);
}

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
    newterm(NULL, stderr, stdin);
    show("lol");
    getch();
    endwin();
    return (0);
}
```

The revised program:

- writes its message using a function `show` which writes to the screen and optionally writes the message
- it checks if the standard output is not a tty using [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html), i.e., you are redirecting the program's output.  Without the check, the two (output and error) would both be written to the screen, messing it up.
- some minor cleanup was done: removing an unused variable, and an unnecessary call to `refresh` (since [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) already did that).

This command

```
lol=`./a.out`
```

will do the requested assignment to `lol` without interfering with the screen updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the output of `a.out` to a shell variable AND see the output in your terminal window, use `tee` ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451278/bash-capture-stdout-to-a-variable-but-still-display-it-in-the-console) is an example). `tee` (shell program) effectively lets you duplicate the output of a process and send it to two places at once (in your case, a shell variable and your terminal).

Example (based on the solution given in the above link):

```
exec 5>&1
lol=$(./a.out | tee > (cat - >&5))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer too but i'm not allowed to use the fcntl.h library. I have just to use open(), close(), write(), malloc(), free(), read(), exit(), signal(), ioctl() and all ncurses' functions... ;/

Comment: you misunderstand- the problem (or at least, the first one I see, and the one @Jean-Baptiste Yunès pointed out) is in the shell code you use to execute `a.out`, not in the C code. I'm talking about the shell program `tee`, not the system call in `fcntl.h`. Read the link I posted in the answer.

Comment: @ErikNyquist : There's no link in your post, and some people (not me) will downvote an answer that points to an external source, rather than summarizing the relevant info in the answer's text.

Comment: OK, fair enough- I'll summarise and add a little example. There is a link, though- click on the word "Here" :)

Comment: The link would give you the following commands `exec 5>&1; a=\`./a.out | tee >(cat - >& 5)\`` in bash.

Comment: I see what you're pointing at. The fact is I need to do it with a limited set of functions and librairies. One of this means is to get in the standard output some specific informations and store them. The thing is I need to first see the virtual screen, but it does'nt come up. Whereas when I execute the ./a.out it's showing up.

Comment: are you saying that you are limited in both the C libraries and the shell programs that you can use? or are you only limited with C libraries?

Comment: Yes, I'll be judged only on this limited set : open(), close(), write(), malloc(), free(), read(), exit(), signal(), ioctl() and all ncurses' functions. A sole : variable=\`.a.out\` should work.

Comment: OK, that's a list of system calls, but again, are you limited in the shell programs (not C libraries or system calls) that you can use to execute your program?

Comment: Yes i will be corrected by a machine called "moulinette" and it will execute some specifics commands.

Comment: OK this is getting confusing. Can you post a snippet (the smallest snippet possible to show us what's required) of the text for the assignment?

Comment: in fact i have to realize a program who list informations past with argv and return those which are selected (thanks to ncurses). I have some news, it's about the file descriptor who changed if we put the program between backquotes...

Comment: that doesn't tell me anything. Please post the actual text that describes this. As in, copy-and-paste.

Comment: Thanks for all, i found the solution <3