# Call an interactive subscript and save its output to variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I currently have a Perl script (that I can't edit) that asks the user a few questions, and then prints a generated output to stdout. I want to make another script that calls this script, allows the user to interact with it as normal, and then stores the output from stdout to a variable.

Here's a really simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

**inner.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Enter a number:";
$reply = <>;
print "$reply";
```

**outer.sh** (based on the answer by Op De Cirkel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451278/bash-capture-stdout-to-a-variable-but-still-display-it-in-the-console))

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Calling inner.pl"
exec 5>&1
OUTPUT=$(./inner.pl | tee >(cat - >&5))
echo "Retrieved output: $OUTPUT"
```

Desired output:

```
$ ./outer.sh
Calling inner.pl
Enter a number: 7
7
Retrieved output: 7
```

However, when I try this, the script will output `Calling inner.pl` before "hanging" without printing anything from inner.sh.

I've found a bit of a workaround by using the `script` command to store the entire inner.sh exchange to a temporary file, and then using `sed` and the like to modify it to my needs. But making temporary files for something fairly trivial like that doesn't make a ton of sense (not to mention `script` likes to add time stamps and `\r`s to everything). Is there any non-`script` way to accomplish this?

Comment: your example `inner.sh` and `outer.sh` worked perfectly for me ...

Comment: Perhaps I over-simplified it then. The original "inner.sh" is actually a Perl script. I don't know anything about Perl, but could that possibly be why my output isn't working? Maybe Perl handles file descriptors and stdout differently? - Just in case, I'll add that detail to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simpler than that. Simply redirect inner's output to a variable with $():

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Calling inner.sh"
OUTPUT=$(./inner.sh)
echo "Retrieved output: $OUTPUT"
```

EDIT:

Now, if there's user interaction with the output in `inner.sh` (example `inner.sh` asks user for a number, prints any operation with it and asks the user to input a new value based on that printed result). Then the better is a temporary file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Calling inner.sh"
TMPFILE=`mktemp`
./inner.sh | tee "$TMPFILE"
OUTPUT=$(cat "$TMPFILE")
rm "$TMPFILE"
echo "Retrieved output: $OUTPUT"
```