# scp doesn't list then when run in subshell script

Tags: bash, scp, subshell, verbose, verbosity

I have a bash script `my_script` which executes:

```
scp -- 'somehost:*.txt' dest_dir
```

now, when I run this script from an interactive shell session, scp lists files as it copies them. But when I run a second script, containing:

```
exec 5>&1
foo=$(my_script | tee /dev/fd/5) || exit -1
```

(see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12451278/1593077) for the motivation) - scp doesn't list the files as it copies them.

Why is that? And can I circumvent this other than by using `scp -v`?

Comment: It probably use stderror to output list of files

Comment: @Ivan: Nope, see Kamilcuk's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that?

`scp` program [checks](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c#L602) if output is a tty, and if it is, then it prints progress. If the output is not a tty, then it doesn't print progress information.

> And can I circumvent this other than by using scp -v?

[How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249723/how-to-trick-a-command-into-thinking-its-output-is-going-to-a-terminal)

Specifically, it may be sufficient to prepend the invocation of `scp` with `unbuffer`:

```
unbuffer scp -- 'somehost:*.txt' dest_dir
```