# Redirecting command output to variable as well as console in bash not working

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a simple task to do from within a shell script - redirect command output to a variable as well as stdout. I already went through [*redirect command output into variable and standard output in ksh*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901568/redirect-command-output-into-variable-and-standard-output-in-ksh), and came up with:

```
VAR1=$(ps -u "${USER}" | awk 'NR>1 {print $NF}' | tee > /proc/$$/fd/1)
```

However the above doesn't work for me. The output displays on `STDOUT` fine, but its not saved in `VAR1`. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unnecessary redirect on that tee command. Use:

```
VAR1=$(ps -u "${USER}" | awk 'NR>1 {print $NF}' | tee /proc/$$/fd/1)
```

They `tee` works is that it copies its input to its output, and also to any files whose names you give as arguments. The redirection just messages up with its pass-through behavior.

Something else you could do - since we're not talking about some long-running command here - is first set the variable, then print its value:

```
VAR1=$(ps -u "${USER}" | awk 'NR>1 {print $NF}' )
echo "$VAR1"
```

... much simpler :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Redirecting command output to variable as well as console in bash:

You can use this trick:

```
var1=$(ps -u "${USER}" | awk 'NR>1 {print $NF}' | tee /dev/tty)
```

or

```
var1=$(ps -u "${USER}" | awk 'NR>1 {print $NF}' | tee /dev/stderr)
```

`tee` command will write output to `/dev/tty` which is your current terminal.

Also suggest you to avoid using all caps variable names to avoid chance of overriding an env var.

PS: Both commands work for me on OSX and Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you checked if the output is working. MY original problem still remains. var1 is not saving the output

Comment: Sending output directly to `/dev/tty` makes it impossible to pipe or redirect stdout.

Comment: @anubhava    No it doesn't work for me. I'm on KSH. The output just shows on `STDOUT`, but is not saved in `VAR1` variable

Comment: @anubhava Even for bash, it doesn't work for me. When I say KSH I mean, only when I run the above line from my shell (default shell).

Comment: @anubhava But even from within bash script doesn't work

Comment: `Kernel 2.6.32-754.14.2.e16`, `OS: RHEL-6.10`

Comment: @anubhava `$ var1=$(ps -u smnd | awk 'NR>1 {print $NF}' | tee > /dev/stderr);echo $var1
ksh
ps
awk
tee
 
$ var1=$(ps -u smnd | awk 'NR>1 {print $NF}' | tee > /dev/tty);echo $var1
ksh
ps
awk
tee
 
$`

As you can clearly see, there is nothing saved in the variable

Comment: Why do you have `>` after `tee` in your command, I suggested `tee /dev/tty` or `tee /dev/stderr` without `>` after `tee`. Just run this in `bash`: **`var1=$(ps -u smnd | awk''NR>1 {print $NF}' | tee /dev/stderr); declare -p var1`**