# Why piping input to "read" only works when fed into "while read ..." construct?

Tags: bash, while-loop, pipe, piping

I've been trying to read input into environment variables from program output like this:

```
echo first second | read A B ; echo $A-$B
```

And the result is:

```
-
```

Both A and B are always empty. I read about bash executing piped commands in sub-shell and that basically preventing one from piping input to read. However, the following:

```
echo first second | while read A B ; do echo $A-$B ; done
```

Seems to work, the result is:

```
first-second
```

Can someone please explain what is the logic here? Is it that the commands inside the `while` ... `done` construct are actually executed in the same shell as `echo` and not in a sub-shell?

Comment: This is BashFAQ #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 75, accepted):

## How to do a loop against *stdin* and get result stored in a variable

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (and other [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) also), when you pipe something to another command via `|`, you will implicitly create a *fork*, a subshell that is a child of current session. The subshell can't affect current session's environment.

So this:

```
TOTAL=0
printf "%s %s\n" 9 4 3 1 77 2 25 12 226 664 |
  while read A B;do
      ((TOTAL+=A-B))
      printf "%3d - %3d = %4d -> TOTAL= %4d\n" $A $B $[A-B] $TOTAL
    done
echo final total: $TOTAL
```

won't give expected result! :

```
  9 -   4 =    5 -> TOTAL=    5
  3 -   1 =    2 -> TOTAL=    7
 77 -   2 =   75 -> TOTAL=   82
 25 -  12 =   13 -> TOTAL=   95
226 - 664 = -438 -> TOTAL= -343
echo final total: $TOTAL
final total: 0
```

Where computed *TOTAL* could'nt be reused in main script.

### Inverting the fork

By using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *Process Substitution*, *Here Documents* or *Here Strings*, you could inverse the fork:

#### Here strings

```
read A B <<<"first second"
echo $A
first

echo $B
second
```

#### Here Documents

```
while read A B;do
    echo $A-$B
    C=$A-$B
  done << eodoc
first second
third fourth
eodoc
first-second
third-fourth
```

outside of the loop:

```
echo : $C
: third-fourth
```

#### Here Commands

```
TOTAL=0
while read A B;do
    ((TOTAL+=A-B))
    printf "%3d - %3d = %4d -> TOTAL= %4d\n" $A $B $[A-B] $TOTAL
  done < <(
    printf "%s %s\n" 9 4 3 1 77 2 25 12 226 664
)
  9 -   4 =    5 -> TOTAL=    5
  3 -   1 =    2 -> TOTAL=    7
 77 -   2 =   75 -> TOTAL=   82
 25 -  12 =   13 -> TOTAL=   95
226 - 664 = -438 -> TOTAL= -343

# and finally out of loop:
echo $TOTAL
-343
```

Now you could use `$TOTAL` in your *main script*.

### Piping to a *command list*

But for working only against *stdin*, you may create a kind of script into the *fork*:

```
printf "%s %s\n" 9 4 3 1 77 2 25 12 226 664 | {
    TOTAL=0
    while read A B;do
        ((TOTAL+=A-B))
        printf "%3d - %3d = %4d -> TOTAL= %4d\n" $A $B $[A-B] $TOTAL
    done
    echo "Out of the loop total:" $TOTAL
  }
```

Will give:

```
  9 -   4 =    5 -> TOTAL=    5
  3 -   1 =    2 -> TOTAL=    7
 77 -   2 =   75 -> TOTAL=   82
 25 -  12 =   13 -> TOTAL=   95
226 - 664 = -438 -> TOTAL= -343
Out of the loop total: -343
```

Note: `$TOTAL` could not be used in *main script* (after last right curly bracket `}` ).

### Using *lastpipe* bash option

As @CharlesDuffy correctly pointed out, there is a bash option used to change this behaviour. But for this, we have to first **disable** *job control*:

```
shopt -s lastpipe           # Set *lastpipe* option
set +m                      # Disabling job control
TOTAL=0
printf "%s %s\n" 9 4 3 1 77 2 25 12 226 664 |
  while read A B;do
      ((TOTAL+=A-B))
      printf "%3d - %3d = %4d -> TOTAL= %4d\n" $A $B $[A-B] $TOTAL
    done

  9 -   4 =    5 -> TOTAL= -338
  3 -   1 =    2 -> TOTAL= -336
 77 -   2 =   75 -> TOTAL= -261
 25 -  12 =   13 -> TOTAL= -248
226 - 664 = -438 -> TOTAL= -686

echo final total: $TOTAL
-343
```

This will work, but I (personally) don't like this because this is not *standard* and won't help to make script readable. Also disabling job control seem expensive for accessing this behaviour.

**Note:** *Job control* is enabled by default only in *interactive* sessions. So `set +m` is not required in normal scripts.

So forgotten `set +m` in a script would create different behaviours if run in a console or if run in a script. This will not going to make this easy to understand or to debug...

Comment: Thank you. Soon after I had posted my question I realized that the `while` loop was still executed in child instead of the parent and that I couldn't use `A` and `B` outside the loop.

Comment: One note here -- there are shells that support creating subshells for the other components of the pipeline, and using the existing shell for the right-hand side. This is `shopt -s lastpipe` in bash; ksh88 and ksh93 behave similarly out-of-the-box.

Comment: It might be worth noting that job control is turned off by default in noninteractive shells (thus, in all scripts not explicitly reenabling it). Thus, the limitation you note is not relevant in all situations. (To be sure, though, having code that doesn't work identically between interactive and noninteractive shells is a disadvantage in and of itself).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Note added... But I don't like this anyways! ;-)

Comment: This answer is monumentally thorough, but it leaves the impression there is still no way to use `read` to capture standard out when you want to put read at the tail of a pipe-like syntax on a single line. This is what the OP was trying to do. You can do this with subshells or grouping, as other answers show. But is there a way to do this both easily and correctly? -- that is, without loops or subshells or groups, and with process substitution?

Comment: @algal see ***Here strings*** and ***Here commands*** paragraphs, in my explanation. `echo blah | read foo` have to be replaced by `read foo < <(echo blah)`

Comment: ... And no, @algal, the op asked about a `while` loop! (look at the title of this page)

Comment: @F.Hauri when I read the body of the question itself, not just the title, it seems to me the OP is trying to put read at the end and is wondering why he or she must use while. They're not trying to use while. And they were trying to put read at the end. Maybe I assume too much.

Answer (score 28):

a much cleaner work-around...

```sh
first="firstvalue"
second="secondvalue"
read -r a b < <(echo "$first $second")
echo "$a $b"
```

This way, read isn't executed in a sub-shell (which would clear the variables as soon as that sub-shell has ended).  Instead, the variables you want to use are echoed in a sub-shell that automatically inherits the variables from the parent shell.

Comment: For readers who may be confused by syntax of <( ....command.... ) - It is called process substitution in bash http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Comment: what if i want (echo "$first"; echo "$second") to go into A and B? (or more actually, a command that outputs two lines, I want the first to go into A and the second into B)

Comment: You can also prevent spawning a subshell just to run echo by doing this: `read -r a b <<< "$first $second"`

Answer (score 24):

First, this pipe-chain is executed:

```
echo first second | read A B
```

then

```
echo $A-$B
```

Because the `read A B` is executed in a subshell, A and B are lost.
If you do this:

```
echo first second | (read A B ; echo $A-$B)
```

then both `read A B` and `echo $A-$B` are executed in the same subshell (see manpage of bash, search for `(list)`

Comment: btw, you don't need subshell. you can simply use grouping.

Comment: @anishsane: That's strange: If you open two console, in first hit `tty` for knowing which pty is used, than on second `watch ps --tty pts/NN` (where NN is in the answer of 1st console). Than in 1st, try: `echo | (sleep 10)` and  `echo | { sleep 10 ; }`, you will see that the second syntax will generate two forks while first bounce only one subshell.

Comment: For anyone else wondering about it, you need to remember spaces and semicolons if you want to use grouping operators instead of creating a subshell: `echo something | { read myvar; echo $myvar; }`

Comment: Thanks, best answer for me.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is the separation between processes: the `read` occurs in a subshell - a separate process which cannot alter the variables in the main process (where `echo` commands later occur).

A pipeline (like `A | B`) implicitly places each component in a sub-shell (a separate process), even for built-ins (like `read`) that usually run in the context of the shell (in the same process).

The difference in the case of "piping into while" is an illusion. The same rule applies there: the loop is the second half of a pipeline, so it's is in a subshell, but the *whole* loop is in the *same* subshell, so the separation of processes does not apply.

Comment: Syntaxe: `A | B` will create **one** separated process for `B`! Not *each component in a sub-shell*: `A` will remain in main (parent) shell! (except if `shopt -s lastpipe` where `A` will be run in a subshell, **but no `B`** !)

Comment: @F.Hauri no, you have that backwards. **A** will always be in a subshell; **B** will be in a subshell _unless_ you use `shopt -s lastpipe`

Comment: `( set x y z ; set a b c | set d e f ; echo "$@" )`   

x y z   

    `( shopt -s lastpipe ; set x y z ; set a b c | set d e f ; echo "$@" )`   

d e f