# How to pipe input to a Bash while loop and preserve variables after loop ends

Tags: bash, while-loop, stdin, pipe

Bash allows to use: `cat <(echo "$FILECONTENT")`

Bash also allow to use: `while read i; do echo $i; done </etc/passwd`

to combine previous two this can be used: `echo $FILECONTENT | while read i; do echo $i; done`

The problem with last one is that it creates sub-shell and after the while loop ends variable `i` cannot be accessed any more.

My question is:

How to achieve something like this: `while read i; do echo $i; done <(echo "$FILECONTENT")` or in other words: How can I be sure that `i` survives while loop?

Please note that I am aware of enclosing while statement into `{}` but this does not solves the problem (imagine that you want use the while loop in function and return `i` variable)

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229058/append-to-an-array-variable-from-a-pipeline-command . Explains all options including the below-mentioned process substitution and `lastpipe` and their pros and cons.

Comment: Related: [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered).

Comment: @codeforester there is more the one dup... Related: [Why piping input to "read" only works when fed into "while read ..." construct?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764018/1765658) and [Read values into a shell variable from a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2746553/1765658)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The correct notation for [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) is:

```
while read i; do echo $i; done < <(echo "$FILECONTENT")
```

The last value of `i` assigned in the loop is then available when the loop terminates.
An alternative is:

```
echo $FILECONTENT | 
{
while read i; do echo $i; done
...do other things using $i here...
}
```

The braces are an I/O grouping operation and do not themselves create a subshell.  In this context, they are part of a pipeline and are therefore run as a subshell, but it is because of the `|`, not the `{ ... }`.  You mention this in the question.  AFAIK, you can do a return from within these inside a function.

---

Bash also provides the [`shopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) builtin and one of its many options is:

> `lastpipe`
>
> If set, and job control is not active, the shell runs the last command of a pipeline not executed in the background in the current shell environment.

Thus, using something like this *in a script* makes the modfied `sum` available after the loop:

```
FILECONTENT="12 Name
13 Number
14 Information"
shopt -s lastpipe   # Comment this out to see the alternative behaviour
sum=0
echo "$FILECONTENT" |
while read number name; do ((sum+=$number)); done
echo $sum
```

Doing this at the command line usually runs foul of 'job control is not active' (that is, at the command line, job control is active).  Testing this without using a script failed.

Also, as noted by [Gareth Rees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68063/gareth-rees) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19571256/15168), you can sometimes use a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings):

```
while read i; do echo $i; done <<< "$FILECONTENT"
```

This doesn't require `shopt`; you may be able to save a process using it.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I know this is right solution and I've marked it as answer so it worked for me. But now when I run `while read i; do echo $i; done < <(cat /etc/passwd); echo $i` It did not return last line two times. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @WakanTanka: I had to experiment a bit...I believe the answer is that the failing read resets `i` to empty, so the echo after the loop echoes a blank line.

Comment: Kudos for the Process Substitution reference. I was unaware of.

Comment: @Wakan Tanka: got same result as yours, i use `while read i; do x=$i; done < <(cat /etc/passwd); echo i=$i; echo x=$x` worked, //maybe those days bash behavior changed ?

Comment: You're a life saver! Been looking for hours for a similar solution. Yours is the only one that worked.

Comment: I'm getting `shopt: lastpipe: invalid shell option name` in `GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release`

Comment: Curious: the manual still documents it.

Answer (score 33):

[Jonathan Leffler explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19571082/68063) how to do what you want using [*process substitution*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), but another possibility is to use a [*here string*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings):

```
while read i; do echo "$i"; done <<<"$FILECONTENT"
```

This saves a process.

Answer (score 1):

This function makes duplicates $NUM times of jpg files (bash)

```
function makeDups() {
NUM=$1
echo "Making $1 duplicates for $(ls -1 *.jpg|wc -l) files"
ls -1 *.jpg|sort|while read f
do
  COUNT=0
  while [ "$COUNT" -le "$NUM" ]
  do
    cp $f ${f//sm/${COUNT}sm}
    ((COUNT++))
  done
done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash provides var default behavior so:

```bash
while read -r line
do
  total=${total:-0}
  total=$((total + $(calculation code)))
done
echo $total
```

This allows the loop to easily capture stdin, for scripts and functions.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest was:

```
while read -r ITEM; do
    OPERATION
done < <(COMMAND)
```

Or in one line:

```
while read -r ITEM; do OPERATION; done < <(COMMAND)
```