# Reading the path of files as string in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh, pmd, command-substitution

My Aim -->
Files Listing from a command has to be read line by line and be used as part of another command.

Description -->
A command in linux returns

```
archive/Crow.java
archive/Kaka.java
mypmdhook.sh
```

which is stored in `changed_files` variable. I use the following while loop to read the files line by line and use it as part of a pmd command

```
while read each_file
do
        echo "Inside Loop --  $each_file"
done<$changed_files
```

I am new to writing shell script but my assumption was that the lines would've been separated in the loop and printed in each iteration but instead I get the following error --

```
mypmdhook.sh: 7: mypmdhook.sh: cannot open archive/Crow.java
archive/Kaka.java
mypmdhook.sh: No such file
```

Can you tell me how I can just get the value as a string and not as a file what is opened. By the way, the file does exist which made me feel even more confused.(and later use it inside a command). I'd be happy with any kind of answer that helps me understand and resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash - How to pipe input to while loop and perserve variables after loop ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570413/bash-how-to-pipe-input-to-while-loop-and-perserve-variables-after-loop-ends)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is that the value of your variable `$changed_files` is substituted into your command, and you get something like

```
while read each_file
do
        echo "Inside Loop -- $each_file"
done < archive/Crow.java 
archive/Kaka.java
mypmdhook.sh
```

then the shell tries to open the file for redirecting the input and obviously fails.

The point is that redirections (e.g. `<`, `>`, `>>`) in most cases accept filenames, but what you really need is to give the contents of the variable to the stdin. The most obvious way to do that is

```
echo $changed_files | while read each_file; do echo "Inside Loop -- $each_file"; done
```

You can also use the `for` loop instead of `while read`:

```
for each_file in $changed_files; do echo "inside Loop -- $each_file"; done
```

I prefer using `while read ...` if there is a chance that some filename may contain spaces, but in most cases `for ... in` will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have data stored in a variable, use a "[here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)" instead of file redirection:

```
changed_files="archive/Crow.java
archive/Kaka.java
mypmdhook.sh"
while read each_file
do
        echo "Inside Loop --  $each_file"
done <<< "$changed_files"
```

```
Inside Loop --  archive/Crow.java
Inside Loop --  archive/Kaka.java
Inside Loop --  mypmdhook.sh
```

Extremely important to quote `"$changed_files"` in order to preserve the newlines, so the while-read loop works as you expect. A rule of thumb: **always** quote variables, unless you knows exactly why you want to leave the quotes off.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing command's output in a variable use `while` loop like this:

```
mycommand | while read -r each_file; do echo "Inside Loop -- $each_file"; done
```

If you're using BASH you can use `process substitution`:

```
while read -r each_file; do echo "Inside Loop -- $each_file"; done < <(mycommand)
```

btw your attempt of `done<$changed_files` will assume that `changed_files` represents a file.