# Get exit code of process substitution with pipe into while loop

Tags: bash, process-substitution

The following script calls another program reading its output in a while loop (see [Bash - How to pipe input to while loop and preserve variables after loop ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570413/bash-how-to-pipe-input-to-while-loop-and-preserve-variables-after-loop-ends)):

```
while read -r col0 col1; do
    # [...]
done < <(other_program [args ...])
```

How can I check for the exit code of `other_program` to see if the loop was executed properly?

Comment: Check as in? you want to write the status to a file (or) see it in stdout?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sup>Note: `ls -d / /nosuch` is used as an example command below, because it fails (exit code `1`) while still producing stdout output (`/`) (in addition to stderr output).</sup>

#### Bash v4.2+ solution:

[ccarton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43737188/45375) works well in principle, but by default the `while` loop runs in a *subshell*, which means that any variables created or modified in the loop will not be visible to the *current* shell.

In **Bash v4.2+**, you can change this by turning the **`lastpipe` option** on, which makes the *last* segment of a pipeline run in the *current* shell;
as in ccarton's answer, the **`pipefail` option** must be set to have `$?` reflect the exit code of the first *failing* command in the pipeline:

```
shopt -s lastpipe  # run the last segment of a pipeline in the current shell
shopt -so pipefail # reflect a pipeline's first failing command's exit code in $?

ls -d / /nosuch | while read -r line; do 
  result=$line
done

echo "result: [$result]; exit code: $?"
```

The above yields (stderr output omitted):

```
result: [/]; exit code: 1
```

As you can see, the `$result` variable, set in the `while` loop, is available, and the `ls` command's (nonzero) exit code is reflected in `$?`.

---

#### Bash v3+ solution:

[ikkachu's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43736589/45375) works well and shows advanced techniques, but it is a bit cumbersome.
Here is a simpler alternative:

```
while read -r line || { ec=$line && break; }; do   # Note the `|| { ...; }` part.
    result=$line
done < <(ls -d / /nosuch; printf $?)               # Note the `; printf $?` part.

echo "result: [$result]; exit code: $ec"
```

- By appending the value of `$?`, the `ls` command's exit code, to the output *without a trailing `\n`* (`printf $?`), `read` reads it in the last loop operation, but indicates failure (exit code 1), which would normally exit the loop.
- We can detect this case with `||`, and assign the exit code (that was still read into `$line`) to variable `$ec` and exit the loop then.

---

**On the off chance that the command's output doesn't have a trailing `\n`**, more work is needed:

```
while read -r line || 
  { [[ $line =~ ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ ]] && ec=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} && line=${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
    [[ -n $line ]]; }
do
    result=$line
done < <(printf 'no trailing newline'; ls /nosuch; printf "/$?")

echo "result: [$result]; exit code: $ec"
```

The above yields (stderr output omitted):

```
result: [no trailing newline]; exit code: 1
```

Comment: Didn't know about `shopt -s lastpipe` so far. I have been using process substitution as an alternative so far, but today I realized that `set -e` doesn't cause shell to abort when there are errors inside the process substitution, so switched back to the more natural looking pipe approach with `lastpipe` option.

Answer (score 8):

At least one way would be to redirect the output of the background process through a named pipe. This would allow to pick up its PID and then get the exit status through `wait`ing  on the PID.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo pipe || exit 1
(echo foo ; exit 19)  > pipe &
pid=$!
while read x ; do echo "read: $x" ; done < pipe
wait $pid
echo "exit status of bg process: $?"
rm pipe
```

If you can use a direct pipe (i.e. don't mind the loop being run in a subshell), you could use Bash's `PIPESTATUS`, which contains the exit codes of all commands in the pipeline:

```
(echo foo ; exit 19) | while read x ; do 
  echo "read: $x" ; done; 
echo "status: ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to use the bash `pipefail` option to propagate the first error code from a pipeline.

```
set -o pipefail
other_program | while read x; do
        echo "Read: $x"
done || echo "Error: $?"
```

Comment: Nicely done, though it's worth mentioning that the `while` loop then runs in a subshell and its variables won't be visible to the current shell. In Bash v4.2+ you can use `shopt -s lastpipe` to prevent this.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use [`coproc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html) (requires 4.0+).

```
coproc other_program [args ...]
while read -r -u ${COPROC[0]} col0 col1; do
    # [...]
done
wait $COPROC_PID || echo "Error exit status: $?"
```

`coproc` frees you from having to setup asynchronicity and stdin/stdout redirection that you'd otherwise need to do in an equivalent `mkfifo`.

Comment: This works great, but it should be mentioned that one has to save `$COPROC_PID` to some other variable since it will be unset when the command terminates, resulting in `wait` to be called without a PID. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338022 for details. It should also be mentioned that this approach may fail when executing commands that are very fast to finish, e.g. `cat <somefile>`. In this case, the command finishes before the loop is entered, resulting in `read` trying to read from the no longer existing file descriptor `${COPROC[0]}`.