# BASH: Trap exit codes from Process Substitution

Tags: bash

Is there any way to catch exit codes from process substitution (in this case: tar) using 'trap' or 'named pipe'?

My script:

```
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
some_command_procesing $LINE
                done < <(tar PJcvf none.tar.xz /none_exist 2>&1; CHECK="${?}" )
```

I know I can write the `$?` to file but I don’t want tu use it. In this case my CHECK var is empty. Or maybe there's other solution?

Comment: What is the behavior expected of this error detection that `set -o pipefail` can't ?

Comment: That would be OK, but in this case the ${PIPESTATUS[*]} array has the value 1 every time. Regardless of whether the tar command ends with an error or not.

Comment: Since Bash version 4.4 there is a way  to get the exit status of a (single) process substitution.  In older versions of Bash there are various workarounds.  See the "Pitfalls" section of [ProcessSubstitution - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get exit code of process substitution with pipe into while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736021/get-exit-code-of-process-substitution-with-pipe-into-while-loop)

Comment: Also see [How to detect an error using process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/376114/264812).