# Running different codes with python

Tags: python, perl

I am working on a project where i need to run a code thousands of times with different arguments. like

```
 gringo some_random_SAT.lp --const n=i |clasp 0
```

Hhere I need to keep changing `i` to from say 1 to 500 and take the information that `some_random_SAT.lp` outputs, then I need to do the same for a c++ code that I have.  Writing all the data to a file. My question is how to do this.

I am not asking for some one to tell me how to do it all, I just would like to know a good book or some where to learn how to do similar things such as this.

I am not attached to python if perl would work better i can do that.

Im running Linux if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a simple bash script to do that for you.

You could use a for loop to repeat the command multiple times with i incrementing each time.

To fetch the output (I guess saving it in a text file would suffice?) you can pipe the output of each execution to a file or even to a seperate file for each execution.

[For Loops in bash](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/)

[How to fetch the output and use i in the file name (if you want each output in a different file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570413/how-to-pipe-input-to-a-bash-while-loop-and-preserve-variables-after-loop-ends)