# Modify piped input

Tags: bash

Think of strings, such as:

```
I have two apples
He has 4 apples 
They have 10 pizzas
```

I would like to substitute every digit number I find with in a string with a different value, calculated with an external script. In my case, the python program `digit_to_word.py` convert a digit number to the alphabetic format, but anything will be ok so that I can get the process.

Expected output:

```
I have two apples
He has four apples 
They have ten pizzas
```

Conceptually:

```
echo "He has four apples" |
while read word;
do
    if [[ "$word" == +([0-9+]) ]]; then
    NUM='${python digit_to_word.py "$word"}'
    $word="$NUM"
fi
done |
other_operation... | etc..
```

I say **conceptually** because I did not get even close to make it work. It is hard to me to even find information on the issue, simply because I do not exactly know how to conceptualize it. At this point, I am mostly reasoning on [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570413/how-to-pipe-input-to-a-bash-while-loop-and-preserve-variables-after-loop-ends), but I am afraid it is not the best way.

Any hint that could be really useful. Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge with me!

Comment: `NUM=$(python digit_to_word.py "$word"); word=$NUM`. Parameter expansions or command substitutions aren't honored in single quotes, and `${...}` is parameter expansion syntax (for shell variables) whereas you needed a command substitution (for external commands). And you can't have a `$` on the left-hand side of an assignment. And setting variables in pipelines generally doesn't do anything useful, because in general (exceptions exist but are out-of-scope of this comment), pipelines are run in subshells which shut down as soon as the pipeline completes.

Comment: Also, `+([0-9+])` matches `4`, but it doesn't match `four`, so how is that logic supposed to decide to call `digit_to_word` when given `four apples` as input?

Comment: It is correct, it should not be called for `four`, but only digits sequences, such as `4` or `10`.

Comment: Gotcha. Still, you aren't replacing the values in the string anywhere in this code. `$pos = value` is valid *awk* code to replace a value in the field whose number is stored in the variable `pos`, but that's awk, not bash.

Comment: Also, `cat "He has four apples"` is trying to open a *file with the name* `He has four apples`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions, I will work on them! I hope I will figure out a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regex='([[:space:]])([0-9]+)([[:space:]])'

echo "He has 4 apples" |
while IFS= read -r line; do
  line=" ${line} "  # pad with space so first and last words work consistently
  while [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; do       # loop while at least one replacement is pending
    pre_space=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}                # whitespace before the word, if any
    word=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}                     # actual word to replace
    post_space=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}               # whitespace after the word, if any
    replace=$(python digit_to_word.py "$word")  # new word to use
    in=${pre_space}${word}${post_space}         # old word padded with whitespace
    out=${pre_space}${replace}${post_space}     # new word padded with whitespace
    line=${line//$in/$out}                      # replace old w/ new, keeping whitespace
  done
  line=${line#' '}; line=${line%' '}            # remove the padding we added earlier
  printf '%s\n' "$line"                         # write the output line
done
```

This is careful to work even in some tricky corner cases:

- `4 score and 14 years ago` only replaces the `4` in `4 score` with `four`, and doesn't also modify the `4` in `14`.
- Input that mixes tabs and whitespaces generates output with the same kinds of whitespace; `printf '1\t2 3\n'` as your input, and you'll get a tab between `one` and `two`, but a space between `two` and `three`.

See this running at https://ideone.com/SOsuAD

Comment: I am impressed by your knowledge of the topic. I hope to be like you, one day. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest this is a better job for perl.

To recreate the scenario:

```
$ cat digit_to_word.sh
case $1 in
4) echo four;;
8) echo eight;;
10) echo ten;;
*) echo "$1";;
esac
$ bash digit_to_word.sh 10
ten
```

Then this

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/ chomp($word = qx{bash digit_to_word.sh $1}); $word /ge' <<END
I have two apples
He has 4 apples
They have 10 pizzas but only 8 cookies
END
```

outputs

```
I have two apples
He has four apples
They have ten pizzas but only eight cookies
```

However, you've already got some python, why don't you implement the replacement part in python too?

Comment: I don't know perl's `qx` behavior, and am curious -- if the pattern weren't limited to digits only, would we need to worry about command injection attacks?

Comment: qx is synonymous with backtick, so yes, if we weren't prefiltering the input with a regex then we'd need to do more work

Comment: for example: `system "bash", "digit_to_word.sh", $anything` will *not* be interpreted by a shell, so is safer. It also does not conveniently return stdout which is a bummer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! By now, I am not considering pearl as an option, but one day I am afraid it will not be only an option anymore, hence I will dive into it!

Answer (score 1):

**Revision**

This approach decomposes each line into two arrays - one for the words and one for the whitespace.  Each line is then reconstructed by interleaving the array elements, with digits translated to words by the Python script.  Thanks to @Charles Duffy for pointing out some common Bash pitfalls with my original answer.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # Decompose the line into an array of words delimited by whitespace
  IFS=" " read -ra word_array <<< $(echo "$line" | sed 's/[[:space:]]/ /g')

  # Invert the decomposition, creating an array of whitespace delimited by words
  IFS="w" read -ra wspace_array <<< $(echo "$line" | sed 's/\S/w/g' | tr -s 'w')

  # Interleave the array elements in the output, translating digits to text
  for ((i=0; i<${#wspace_array[@]}; i++))
  do
    printf "%s" "${wspace_array[$i]}"
    if [[ "${word_array[$i]}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
      printf "%s" "$(digit_to_word.py ${word_array[$i]})"
    else
      printf "%s" "${word_array[$i]}"
    fi
  done
  printf "\n"
done < sample.txt
```

Comment: See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), as well as [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) describing the safer practice.

Comment: Moreover, `word_array=($line)` falls afoul of [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). If you have a word of `*`, it'll be replaced with a list of files in the current directory. And you're losing details around the whitespace -- how much is used, whether it's a tab or a space, where the newlines are, etc.

Comment: (That's in part because the `for line in` is actually assigning not lines but individual words to `$line`; see the links for more details on why).

Comment: ...also, `printf` format strings should be constant. Use `printf '%s ' "$word"` instead so a double backslash doesn't change to a single one, `\t` doesn't change to a tab, `%%` doesn't change to `%`, etc.

Comment: Wow.  Great tips here.  Thanks!  I'll plan to revise my answer with these pitfalls in mind.

Comment: `while read -r -a word_array; do ...` is better than `for line in ...` + `word_array=($line)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It really gave me useful insight on the mechanisms I should consider.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` for this. Here's an example:

```
$ echo "He has 4 apples" | sed 's/4/four/'
He has four apples
```

Looking at the example data though, `sed` might not be a good fit. If you see "1", you want to replace with "one", but your example replaced "10" with "ten". Do you need to support multi-digit numbers, such as replacing "230" with "two hundred and thirty"?

Comment: If a series of digit is met, the python script operates a transformation, in my intentions.