# Getting the latest python 3 version programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to get the latest python source from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/.
While posting this, the latest version is 3.9.1. I do not want to hardcode 3.9.1 in my code to get the latest version and keep on updating the version when a new version comes out. I am using OS ubuntu 16.04

Is there a programmatic way to get the latest python version (using curl) and use that version to get the latest source?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 is the os

Comment: You can scrape from this url `https://www.python.org/doc/versions/` and read id being  `python-documentation-by-version`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and couldn't find anything better than scraping the downloads page. You mentioned curl, so I'm assuming you want a shell script. I ended up with this:

```sh
url='https://www.python.org/ftp/python/'

curl --silent "$url" |
    sed -n 's!.*href="\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)/".*!\1!p' |
    sort -rV |
while read -r version; do
    filename="Python-$version.tar.xz"
    # Versions which only have alpha, beta, or rc releases will fail here.
    # Stop when we find one with a final release.
    if curl --fail --silent -O "$url/$version/$filename"; then
        echo "$filename"
        break
    fi
done
```

This relies on `sort -V`, which I believe is specific to GNU coreutils. That shouldn't be a problem on Ubuntu.

If you're using this in a larger script and want to use the `version` or `filename` variables after the loop, see [How to pipe input to a Bash while loop and preserve variables after loop ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570413/how-to-pipe-input-to-a-bash-while-loop-and-preserve-variables-after-loop-ends).

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```
$ cat latest_python_version.py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "https://www.python.org/doc/versions/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

# Search for
# <div class="section" id="python-documentation-by-version">
# ...
# </div>
div = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "python-documentation-by-version"})

# Get the first link. It will be something like
# <li><a class="reference external" href="https://docs.python.org/release/3.11.0/">Python 3.11.0</a>,
#  documentation released on 24 October 2022.</li>
link = div.find("li")

# x.contents will be something like ['Python 3.11.0']
x = link.find("a", attrs={"href": re.compile("^https*://")})

# extract the latest version which will be something like '3.11.0'
matches = re.search("Python (.*)$", x.contents[0])
version = matches.group(1)
print(version)
```

Sample run:

```
$ python latest_python_version.py
3.11.0
```