# Bash: variable not setting in if

Tags: bash, shell, archlinux

trying out linux for the first time and learning bash just for fun. Trying to write a script.

Here's a piece of my code (bash):

```
sudo pacman -Suy | if grep --color=always -e "^" -e "there is nothing to do"; then pup=0; else pup=1; fi;
```

When I try to echo the variable, nothing returns. I've confirmed multiple ways that the variable is not being set at all. When I try to set it out of the if statement, echo $var works just fine.

Here's a good chunk of my code for context:

```
case $yn in
        [yY] ) echo running only yay -Suy;
           echo running...;
           yay -Suy | if grep --color=always -e "^" -e "there is nothing to do"; then yup=0; else yup=1; fi; 
           break;;
        [nN] ) echo not updating;
           echo exiting...;
           exit;;
        [pP] ) running only pacman -Suy;
           echo running...;
           sudo pacman -Suy | if grep --color=always -e "^" -e "there is nothing to do"; then pup=0; else pup=1; fi;
           break;;
        [bB] ) echo running full sys update;
           echo running...;
           sudo pacman -Suy | if grep --color=always -e "^" -e "there is nothing to do"; then pup=0; else pup=1; fi; 
           yay -Suy | if grep --color=always -e "^" -e "there is nothing to do"; then yup=0; else yup=1; fi;
           break;;
        * ) echo invalid response;;
esac

done

if [ "$pup" -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "Pacman has updated something."
elif [ "$pup" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Pacman has not updated anything."
else
   :
fi
if [ "$yup" -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "Yay has updated something."
elif [ "$yup" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Yay has not updated anything."
else
   :
fi
```

It being a oneliner isn't the problem. When I replace pup=0 with "echo '0'", it returns 0 no problem. I tried fiddling with the last if statement and no change.

Comment: Pipeline components are transient (it's possible to change bash's configuration to make this no longer true for the rightmost component, but the shell has to be configured a very particular way to make that true). Your code is setting the variable just fine, but it's doing so _in a subshell_ that exits the moment the pipeline finishes execution.

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: See [How to pipe input to a Bash while loop and preserve variables after loop ends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19570413/4154375).

Answer (score 3):

The variable assignment is in a pipeline. That runs in a subshell, so variable assignments don't persist.

Put the pipeline in the condition of the `if`, rather than putting the whole `if` statement in the pipeline. E.g. change

```
... | if grep ... ; then ...; else ...; fi
```

to

```
if ... | grep ...; then ...; else ...; fi
```