# Free-style Project. How to iterate over multiple-values parameter

Tags: bash, loops, ubuntu, jenkins

In my Free-style Project Jenkins job I have a parameter called "COMPONENETS" that takes one or multiple strings divided by space.

[image]

If I use this parameter passed as single string (`first`) in bash script stage I can achieve what I need (`/path/to/first-*.tar.gz` will be handled):

```
<DO SOMETHING WITH> /path/to/${COMPONENTS}-*.tar.gz
```

but when I try to update my Job with handling, for instance, string with two values (`first second`):

```
for COMPONENT in $(echo "${COMPONENTS}"); do
    <DO SOMETHING WITH> /path/to/$COMPONENT-*.tar.gz
done
```

that doesn't work as values seem to be empty - I got error

```
'/path/to/-*.tar.gz': No such file or directory
'/path/to/-*.tar.gz': No such file or directory
```

So how should I iterate through list parameter on Jenkins correctly?

Comment: Your `$COMPONENTS` contains the entire string passed in the UI. Use [this-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212526/5291015) from the linked duplicate to solve the issue you are seeing

Comment: @Inian Thanks for the quick response. But the issue is not about how to split the string into sub-strings by space. The loop is working correctly locally in Ubuntu Terminal, but doesn't work specifically in bash script in Jenkins job

Comment: `I have a parameter` _Where_ do you "have" that parameter? Where do you set `COMPONENTS` variable? Also `$(echo` is pointless, just `$COMPONENTS`.

Comment: @KamilCuk `COMPONENTS` is a Free-style project Jenkins job parameter that I want to pass to a bash script ("Execute shell") job stage. `for COMPONENT in ${COMPONENTS}; do` didn't work as well...

Comment: Are you open to another solution?

Comment: @JRichardsz this task currently postponed since blocked, but surely I will try your solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

## It works

I tried your code and it works as expected. Check char by char

```
echo "COMPONENTS: $COMPONENTS"

for COMPONENT in $(echo "${COMPONENTS}"); do
    echo "/path/to/$COMPONENT-*.tar.gz"
done
```

**Build params**

[image]

[image]

**Jenkins version** : 2.426.1

## Another option

This works too and is more simple

```bash
for COMPONENT in ${COMPONENTS}; do
    echo "/path/to/$COMPONENT-*.tar.gz"
done
```

Result

[image]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1469863/3957754

## With regex

You could use this to  elaborate complex splits

```
echo $COMPONENTS | sed 's/ /\n/g' | 
while read COMPONENT; do
  echo "/path/to/$COMPONENT-*.tar.gz"
done
```

Result

[image]

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71055887/3957754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19571082/3957754

## Groovy

If you are having problems I advice to use a scripted pipeline in which with groovy you could do anything you need:

```
String[] COMPONENTS = param.COMPONENTS.split("\\s");
for (String COMPONENT : COMPONENTS) {
    sh "/path/to/$COMPONENT-*.tar.gz"
}
```