# Using xargs arguments twice

Tags: sed, remote-access, xargs

I need to check if local file is same as remote host file.

The file locations are like below:
File1 at Local machine 
./remotehostname/home/a/b/scripts/xyz.cpp

File2 at remote machine 
remotehostname:/home/a/b/scripts/xyz.cpp

I intend to compare these 2 files, using the command

```
diff  ./remotehostname/home/a/b/scripts/xyz.cpp remotehostname:/home/a/b/scripts/xyz.cpp


 find . -type f | grep -v .svn |xargs -I % diff %
```

I need to change % to take remotehost and compare the file.
Not sure how to apply sed on %. Or is there a better way to compare such files.

One way could be to save the list of files and then apply sed on that file, but I think there should be an even better way. Also the diff doesnt work on remote hosts, maybe I need to use output of dry rsync?

Comment: You should probably have a look at `rsync`. Its jobs is to compare file hierarchies (local or remote) and synchronize them if needed. It has a `--dry-run` option that just does the comparison, not the sync.

Comment: You can create a script that transforms the paths and does the comparison, and then run *it* from `xargs`.

Comment: What's the actual question here? You can use the argument to `%` as many times as you want in the command.

Comment: @EtanReisner % =local/file/path I want to compare local/file/path to remoteserver:/local/file/path. , mean I need to apply sed on % to create it as my second argument to diff command. eg. diff % %(with some pattern replaced) ie. if 1st %=file/path 2nd % should be remoteserver:file/path

Comment: Ah. Then you don't want to use `-I` at all and you want to pass the filename to a shell script as the argument to `xargs`. `.... | xargs sh -c 'diff "$1" "$(sed .... <<<"$1")"' - {} \;` or similar.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with `xargs`, but I prefer to use `while read` in bash.

#### xargs method

```
find . -type f | grep -v .svn | sed 's/.*/& remotehostname:&/' | xargs -n2 diff
```

The sed command duplicates the input and makes whatever modifications you need. The xargs then passes the inputs to `diff` two at a time. This will *not* work if any filename contain spaces.

#### bash method

```
find . -type f | grep -v .svn | while read line; do
    diff "$line" "remotehostname:$line"
done
```

The bash `read` command reads a line from stdin, places it in the name variable, `$line`, and returns true. You can then put whatever you like inside the loop, so you get total freedom to rewrite the filename however you need. When the input runs out, `read` returns false, and the loop exits.

Note that piping things into loops has [some interesting side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763942/bash-why-piping-input-to-read-only-works-when-fed-into-while-read-const) that are not relevant here, but might bite you one day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the actual difference (and not just whether they differ - which `rsync` is brilliant for telling you) then you can do this using GNU Parallel:

```
find . -type f | grep -v .svn |
  parallel diff {} '<(ssh {= s:./::;s:/.*:: =} cat {= s:([^/]+/){2,2}::;$_=::shell_quote_scalar($_) =})'

s:./::;s:/.*:: = hostname from path
s:([^/]+/){2,2}:: = rest of path
::shell_quote_scalar = \-quote special chars as needed by the shell
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: Thanks, but I am still missing the trick to modify path to remoteserver. eg. my local file path is ./remoteservername/a/b/c/d.cpp and file to comapare with is at remoteservername:/a/b/c/d.cpp . So somehow I need to extract remoteservername from filepath