# Why is exit my status valid in command line but not within bash script? (Bash)

Tags: bash, githooks, exit-code

There are a few layers here, so bear with me.

My `docker-container ssh -c"echo 'YAY!'; exit 25;"` command executes `echo 'YAY!'; exit 25;` in my docker container. It returns:

```
YAY
error:  message=YAY!
, code=25
```

I need to know if the command within the container was successful, so I append the following to the command:

```
docker-container ssh -c"echo 'YAY!'; exit 25;"  >&1 2>/tmp/stderr; cat /tmp/stderr | grep 'code=' | cut -d'=' -f2 | { read exitStatus; echo $exitStatus; }
```

This sends the `stderr` to /tmp/stderr and, with the `echo $exitStatus` returns:

```
YAY!
25
```

So, this is exactly what I want. I want the $exitStatus saved to a variable. My problem is, I am placing this into a bash script (GIT pre-commit) and when this exact code is executed, the exit status is `null`.

Here is my bash script:

```
# .git/hooks/pre-commit

if [ -z ${DOCKER_MOUNT+x} ];
then
    docker-container ssh -c"echo 'YAY!'; exit 25;"  >&1 2>/tmp/stderr; cat /tmp/stderr | grep 'code=' | cut -d'=' -f2 | { read exitStatus; echo $exitStatus; }

    exit $exitStatus;
else
    echo "Container detected!"
fi;
```

Comment: Eh? You *can't possibly* be getting `null` as an exit status; the only possible values are integers. You might have `0`, but you can't have `null`.

Comment: [ShellCheck](http://ShellCheck.net) automatically detects this issue.

Comment: *nod* -- if you expect the `exit` in the pipeline to cause the script to exit, well... something that explicitly asked why that doesn't happen with the irrelevant context factored out would actually be a much clearer question than this is.

Comment: This is in a respect duplicative of [bash: why piping to read only works when fed into `while read` construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763942/bash-why-piping-input-to-read-only-works-when-fed-into-while-read-const), insofar as understanding the answer to the other explains why this doesn't work. [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) is pertinent reading as well.

Comment: BTW, writing to `/tmp/stderr` is dangerous if you're on a shared system. Two scripts using that same name at once is a problem, but a much *worse* problem is if another user (or a compromised network service --
and remember, `/tmp` is world-writable!) replaces `/tmp/stderr` with a symlink to a file you have permission to write to but they don't, and which they want to see deleted. Don't use hardcoded temporary filenames -- this is what `mktemp` exists to avoid.

Comment: BTW, `cat foo | grep bar` is significantly less efficient than `grep bar <foo` -- and `cat foo | grep bar | cut -d= -f2` can be replaced with, say, `awk -F= '/bar/ { print $2 }' <foo` to do everything in one process.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're setting the variable in a pipeline. Each command in the pipeline is run in a subshell, and when the subshell exits the variable are no longer available.

bash allows you to run the pipeline's *last* command in the current shell, but you also have to turn off job control

An example

```
# default bash
$ echo foo | { read x; echo x=$x; } ; echo x=$x
x=foo
x=

# with "lastpipe" configuration
$ set +m; shopt -s lastpipe

$ echo foo | { read x; echo x=$x; } ; echo x=$x
x=foo
x=foo
```

Add `set +m; shopt -s lastpipe` to your script and you should be good.

---

And as Charles comments, there are more efficient ways to do it. Like this:

```
source <(docker-container ssh -c "echo 'YAY!'; exit 25;" 2>&1 1>/dev/null | awk -F= '/code=/ {print "exitStatus=" $2}')
echo $exitStatus
```