# Why read builtin command has different behaviour on zsh and bash?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

running following command on zsh

```
zsh$ echo Hello | read str ; echo "str is: "$str

str is: Hello
```

whereas in bash, it doesn't work

```
bash$ echo Hello | read str ; echo "str is: "$str
str is:
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763942/why-piping-input-to-read-only-works-when-fed-into-while-read-construct/) mentions `read` command runs in subshell so current session has no clue about it. I'm not able to find why it works in zsh.

Comment: Because in `zsh` it doesn't run in a subshell? `ksh93` will also not run `read` in a subshell.

Comment: In `ksh` and `zsh`, all except the last command in a pipeline will run in a subshell

Comment: @mohitmun : The other comments tell you all you need to know for your particular case, but also note that even without the context of a subshell, the `read` commands in bash and zsh are not identical. After all, bash and zsh are pretty different in many ways.

Answer (score 3):

The `read` command has the same behaviour in both shells, but `bash` runs the `read` in a subshell whereas `zsh` does not.

Some shells don't need to use a subshell for the `read` in your example (in general, the last command in a pipeline).

To avoid having to switch to another shell interpreter, you may have the `read` read from something other than a pipe:

```
read str <<<'hello'
printf 'str is %s\n' "$str"
```

Or, if all you want is to output the string, output it in the same subshell:

```
echo 'hello' | { read str && printf 'str is %s\n' "$str"; }
```