# How to assign command output to variables with bash and read

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to assign the output of a command to multiple variables, one per output "word". Doing (bash on linux)

```
echo foo bar baz | read FOO BAR BAZ
echo $FOO $BAR $BAZ
```

shows only empty strings. Doing

```
read FOO BAR BAZ < <(echo foo bar barz)
echo $FOO $BAR $BAZ
```

works as expected. What's wrong here? I thought using a pipe was the most obvious and right way to do that.

Comment: Pipes create shubshells which cannot alter the non-subshell environment. I'll link a duplicate with answers in a minute.

Comment: Since you already have a working code I guess you just want an explanation of what is hapenning. User [pbhd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1799742/pbhd) nicely explains it [in his post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764174/5521670). Piped operations happen in a subshell and therefore any declared variables are accessible only inside it.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143959/187122) explains the problem but is on unix SE. When someone finds a good duplicate on StackOVerflow please link it. I'm sure there is one.

Comment: See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 4):

```
echo foo bar baz | read FOO BAR BAZ
echo $FOO $BAR $BAZ
```

In this case it prints nothing. The reason is because pipe creates a subshell in which `FOO`, `BAR` and `BAZ` get values.

```
echo foo bar baz | { read FOO BAR BAZ ;  echo $FOO $BAR $BAZ ;}
```

Try this, it will print correct value of all variables. Here, the braces encapsulated the `echo` command to run in the same subshell in which the variables are read.

```
read FOO BAR BAZ < <(echo foo bar barz)
echo $FOO $BAR $BAZ
```

In this case everything happens in the same shell, so you see the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

One addition to Mihir's answer -

```
read a b c <<< "$( echo 1 2 3 )" # a here-string
```