# How to redirect the output of time function to a variable

Tags: unix, time, solaris, ksh

i have the following problem that i would need your assistance to solve. 
I have a function lets call it `"fun"`, and i want to time how much time the function needs to be run, so i have this line added in the script:

```
time fun;
```

So like this, it will print also the time that the function needed to run. Point is that i want to redirect the output of the `time` into a variable, so i can manipulate it later as i see fit. My failed tries already:

```
TIME=`time fun`
time fun | tail -3
etc..
```

Does anyone know how this can be done, so for example the desired result would be:

```
somehow add the time output in TIME variable.
```

so if i would `echo $TIME`
I would get result like this,

```
real    0m0.45s
user    0m0.35s
sys     0m0.00s
```

Thank you for your time!!

**P.S.**

I run the script on ksh, on an oracle solaris system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect output to a variable in this shell function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559076/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-a-variable-in-this-shell-function)

Comment: @AniMenon how is that dublicate with the one you are talking about.... i am asking about `time` function and to redirect to a variable... jesus.... also that is in bash, and i am asking about ksh....

Comment: the time function is working for you, your problem was in redirecting the output which is actually a duplicate of the above question.

Comment: @AniMenon no, this is not a duplicate. `time` behaves differently, so the solution provided in the question you link is not useful here. Test it and test my answer to cross check.

Comment: My dear @AniMenon you still dont see it do you?? What was given as an answer there i already tried it, you could see it on my post, but also i see that you didnt bother reading it. If i would like to get the output of the function that would have worked fine for me, though i need somehow to catch what the time was returning, and that couldnt be done in that way, look at the solution fedorqui gave me, which is actually what i was looking for as well, and compare it with the selected answer from the post you marked as dublicate. Not the same thing darling :)

Comment: hedgehog cool. And @fedorqui yes the redirection is there here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what [How can I redirect the output of 'time' to a variable or file?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032) describes:

```
your_time=$( { time fun ; } 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

Here we are redirecting stdout to `/dev/null` so that we get rid of it and just get stderr. This is a particular case of:

```
foo=$( { time ls; } 2>&1 )            # More efficient version.
```

#### Test

We are going to `ls` two files: one that exists (`myfile`) and one that does not (`asdfjasdkfl`).

```
$ touch myfile
$ time_info=$( { time ls myfile asdfjasdkfl; } 2>&1 >/dev/null)
$ echo "$time_info"
ls: cannot access asdfjasdkfl: No such file or directory

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: well i cannot open the link you sent me, cause my pc has a whitelist for broswer. but i just tried what you recommented and it works just fine, as always you have been targeted efficient and correct!! tnx fedorqui!

Comment: I know what you meant on the edit you did on my post btw, but i just added it, because many times people dont bother to read what you have tagged and give you answers for other languages, like ksh - bash, thats why i added it on the post :) tnx anyways

Comment: i got one more question for you regarding this matter.... i did as you told me and everything is working fine, so this is how it looks now. 
`TIME1=$( { time awkfun ; } 2>&1 >/dev/null);`   .... but one problem now is that awkfun is actually printing some stuff, but now if i use it like this, it is running and i take the time, but it doesnt print the stuff.... Any suggestions???

Comment: @hedgehog you may want to check [`tee`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1221833/1983854).

Comment: i see, that would be done though in the case that i needed to store the output, what i need it to do is just print it on the terminal. because the moment i used the /dev/null to recurse the output of time the actual functionality of the function awkfun which is to output something is gone. I really dont get why it doesnt print it as long as the whole script is running.... any ideas still?

Comment: @hedgehog this sounds like you should ask a new question with all the details in it, since it is getting quite far away from this question!

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
variable=$(time fun)
```

Example :

```
var=$(time ls -l) ## or var="$(time ( ls -l ) 2>&1 >/dev/null )"
echo "$var"
```

Output:

```
##displays output of ls command and the time taken
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Alternate method :

Just use `time` directly on your execution statement of the script.

Example : `time ./fun`

Comment: hmmmm, first of all the example you gave doesnt work i already tried it, you could see it on my post, second of all i am talking about a function in a script i am not talking about a whole script, there are much more things inside the whole script, so i cannot use time like that, it has to be used on a function.

Comment: The example I have put up was tried inside a script & it works. You may also run it like this : `mytime="$(time ( ls -l ) 2>&1 >/dev/null )"` and then print it `echo $mytime`

Comment: i didnt say your script doesnt work, i said that this it doesnt work for me. because it doesnt do what i need because time has a different behaviour with functions. anyways fedorqui answered it already before you, thanks for the reply though.