# Why python function returned value is not assigned to shell variable?

Tags: python-2.7, shell

**python:**

```
for line in sys.stdin:
  foo(line)
def foo(name):
  return "hello " + name
```

**shell:**

```
welcome_saying = $(echo "Tom" | python welcome.py)
echo "$welcome_saying"
```

I expected "hello Tom" printed in console, but none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print("hello" + name)`

`return` returns the value to the calling function, not to the console.

Then you have to write the pipe properly: [How do I redirect output to a variable in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559076/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-a-variable-in-shell)

Comment: I expected to use the returned value `welcome_saying`, not to print on console.

Comment: oh i see, it must write to stdout either from `print` or  `sys.stdout.write(welcome())`

Comment: Yes, and then you need to put the output in your variable.

Comment: but it also assigned stderr to shell variable.