# `gcloud builds list` can't capture command output in variable

Tags: bash, gcloud

I have some working code which follows the pattern seen below.

`FIRST_BILLING_ACCOUNT=$(gcloud beta billing accounts list --filter=open=true --format="value(name)" --limit=1)`

Check output with: `$FIRST_BILLING_ACCOUNT`

Prints my billing account's name.

And like this:

`REGION=$(gcloud app describe --format="value(locationId.scope())")`

Check output with: `$REGION`

Prints the region.

## Problem

This does not work:

`OUT=$(gcloud builds list --ongoing)`

It prints the output: `Listed 0 items.` and does not save the value in $OUT.

Other things which do not work, pulled from here: [How do I redirect output to a variable in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559076/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-a-variable-in-shell)

`OUT="$(gcloud builds list --ongoing)"`

`gcloud builds list --ongoing | read OUT`

`read OUT < <(gcloud builds list --ongoing)`

I even tried this:

```
echo "gcloud builds list --ongoing" >> tst.sh
chmod +x tst.sh
OUT=$(./tst.sh)
$OUT
```

And it had the same result.

I want to know 2 things: How do I capture this command's output? And **why do different gcloud commands seem to behave differently?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured it out. It's printing to STDERR instead of STDOUT. To capture:

`OUT=$(gcloud builds list --ongoing 2>&1)`

I'll just have to use `2>&1` in all of my checks from now on.